# Function name must be a string in json_encode

Tags: php

I'm not sure what the problem is, I get the error "Function name must be a string":

```
<?php
    $prodId = $_GET('productId');
    echo json_encode(array( 'productId' =>  $prodId) );
?>
```

I just want to echo back a `XMLHTTPRequest` `JSON` request, to make sure the `GET` is working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$prodId = $_GET('productId');
```

should be

```
$prodId = $_GET['productId'];
```